# javascript context with Math.max

Tags: javascript, scope, apply

I was learning through javascript's context and `.apply()` and `.call()` function and am having trouble with one particular statement.

```
Math.max.apply( Math, array );
```

can you explain how it works to provide the maximum number??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` is a function's method that calls a the function with the given context object and arguments provided as an array:

```
var ops = {
   sum : function (a, b) {
       return a + b;
   }
}

ops.sum.apply(ops, [4, 6]); // 10

// is equivalent to:

ops.sum(4, 6);
```

`Math.max` returns the largest of zero or more numbers:

```
Math.max(1,2,3,4); // 4
```

So, using `apply`, you have:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, [1,2,3,4]); // 4
```

That is equivalent to the code above.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

This calls the method `Math.max` with `this === Math` (not really necessary as it's pretty much a static method) and all elements from `array` as arguments.